# Callback URL for affiliate

Tags: php

I have an affiliate website that I use, they give me parameters when they redirect visitor to me, I save this parameters on my database.

then when a customer makes an order I should pass this parameters back to them

they ask me to use callback for url like this

```
www.advertismentsite.com/callback?=parameters
```

how could I do it without redirecting the customer,

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php you can use file_get_contents

```
$result = file_get_contents('www.advertismentsite.com/callback?=parameters');
```

After calling the remote file, the answer is in $result.

Comment: Thanks a lot , this slove my issue

Comment: @Oliver, thanks: upvote. Is there any way to retrieve the http response code (eg: 404 not found) or the response headers?

Comment: Word of advice, beware not to run it more than once, also note that in this particular example, javascript is absent, many advertising/conversion/tracking pixels require js even if this particular one does not.

Comment: you mean not to run it more than once in a single script? why?

Comment: @BeetleJuice AFAIK it's possible only if you create a context and pass as a `$context` parameter. Getting response code is easy with [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/)

Comment: @BeetleJuice, depends on the script but for instance you don't want to send another sell if the user say reloads the thank you page for instance. This is especially true if you are paying the advertiser which you probably are.

Comment: I see what you're saying. For fraud prevention.